# AngularJS | Check for max and min input values on both arrow and user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, controller, minmax

I have an input text field. I want to check that a value should not exceed 20 and should be at least 1. **This is my HTML:**

```
                <input 
                    type="number"
                    class="form-control input-rounded"
                    ng-model="Ctrl.new.runner"
                    ng-change="Ctrl.newChangeAction(Ctrl.new)"
                    min={{minRunnerValue}}
                    max={{maxRunnerValue}}
                    ng-model-options="{debounce:500}"
                    > 
                    <span ng-show="Ctrl.newObject.runnerWarning">
                        <i>{{Ctrl.Object.runnersWarning}}</i>
                    </span>
```

**MY CTRL:**

```
  $scope.runnerWarning = "";

  ctrl.minRunnerValue = 1;
  ctrl.maxRunnerValue = 20;
```

**I basically want to check for both user input and arrow input.(Up and down). Up and down is working with this code but user input doesn't. Another problem is that the warning is never getting through.**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know there are other questions like this. Don't mark it as duplicates. They don't solve user input, and error handling.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Binding to form and control state](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I made a simple sample througt your peice code

I wish this helps,

```
<!-- JsBin link -->
```

https://jsbin.com/dokajirewu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question still remains. How to handle and display my warning. FYI, my warning is coming from a constant file. It is something like this. `runnersWarning = 'Maximum number of runners is ' + maxRunnerValue;` Every answer has it up until now. My example above works with just arrows. I want to handle user input and display this message.

Comment: Ideally a watcher should be placed and watch for changes in the input text. And depending on its value, a span should appear, containing the warning. Should be bind with `ng-binding` or with and `ng-if`. Don't really know.